# How to troubleshoot a Windows 10 laptop that has a circle that spins forever when trying to logon after waking from sleep

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, logging, login-screen

I have some users who are struggling with this problem. They are Dell laptops running Windows 10 and after the computer goes to sleep (shut lid, time out, etc) it is unable to log back in. Once the computer wakes up, the user goes to log in and they are able to get this far but once the logon circle starts spinning and the profile starts loading it loads forever and never goes into Windows. The only thing the user can do is manually shut down and then it works.

It seems to be happening to happen to users both on and off our network (but all reports are wireless) but I'm less interested in a resolution (that would be nice, of course) but I'd really like to know **how to troubleshoot this**. What logs do I need to enable or look in to see what could be causing these delays and hangs when logging in?

Comment: Since it's a login issue off the network, I'd look to a group policy that logs onto the network after sleep timeout. That may be a security rule to prevent disconnecting a timed-out PC from the LAN to get access without full login.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks for the reponse. Actually today I got my first report of it happening on the network, however all reports have been on WiFi